# Get parent id by term id

Tags: terms

I have the `id` of a `term`. Which is the function to call to get the `parent id` of the term?

Comment: This might be useful: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/if-current-taxonomy-has-child-andor-parent

Answer (score 19):

If you already have the term, like the term is an actual object you could use `$term->parent`. Otherwise you can do something like this:

```
$term = get_term($id, 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_HERE');
$termParent = ($term->parent == 0) ? $term : get_term($term->parent, 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_HERE');
```

The 2nd portion of this is a shorthand if-else, IF it doesn't have a parent, then we assign it itself, otherwise we get the parent.

Comment: If only the ID is needed (and not term object), modify line #2 to: `$termParent = $term ? $term->parent : false;`. This will either give you the parent ID, or false. Not the object. Also saves a query.

Answer (score 0):

To get all parents of "category" you can use :

```
get_ancestors($term_id, 'category', 'taxonomy');
```